# Is it safe to send the result of AuthenticationTokenCreateContext.SerializeTicket to the client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, refresh-token

I'm struggling to find information about how sensitive is the result of Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationTokenCreateContext.SerializeTicket

Ideally, I'd like to avoid storing it on the server, and instead just send it to the client (as a token) so that I can deserialize it in AuthenticationTokenProvider.ReceiveAsync

Do I need to encrypt it? Is it a problem to send it to the client even after encryption?

All implementations I've seen store this ticket server side, and only send an identifier to the client. I don't know if there is a reason not to send the ticket itself?

Comment: what that tokens allows to do an attacker if he stole it?

Comment: The attacker could log in my application in place of the intended recipient, until expiration of the ticket, but that's expected. However I don't know if something worst can happen. All implementations I've seen store this ticket server side, and only send an identifier to the client. I don't know what's the reason not to send the ticket itself?

Comment: If is just for authentication you cannot do anything, you must trust in your client. You cannot do anything if the credentials are stolen. A little improvement is link the token with the client IP.

Comment: Another concern is if an attacker could forge a ticket. I don't know if the serialization method encrypts or signs the ticket, so that it can check it has really been generated by the server. If an attacker can forge a ticket, then he can gain access to the application even without intercepting a ticket first. But there is no documentation about this serialization method, I don't know what it does.

Comment: Normally, generate a valid token/ticket computationally is impossible or it must be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up storing the tickets on the server, and only sending an identifier to the clients.

After thinking a bit more, I found the following advantages with this method:

- Clients can still use the ticket (by sending back the identifier)
- Tickets can be invalidated server-side (by deleting them from the database), for example when the user password is changed
- There is no more issue of knowing what data is sensitive or not (the ticket always stays on the server)
- It prevents ticket forgery (ticket identifiers are random Guids in my implementation)